# Where is Tai Lung after his defeat?

Tags: kung-fu-panda

In *Kung Fu Panda 3*, Po uses the Wuxi Finger Hold...

> ...to send himself and Kai to the spirit world since he is unable to use the technique on Kai directly.

But, in *Kung Fu Panda*, Po uses the Wuxi Finger Hold to defeat Tai Lung. Does this mean Tai Lung is

> in the spirit world? Would Kai have taken his Chi, despite Tai Lung's Chi not being on-screen during the events of KFP3?

Or is Tai Lung just simply dead?

Comment: I think dead due to lack of chi? He was not a Master of chi anymore than any of the others.... Po had an advantage due to his Panda-ness but Tai Lung would not have.

Comment: @Rincewind: Crane, Mantis, Viper, and Monkey were all turned into green gems. They didn't have any specialized training with Chi. They basically had the same training as Tai Lung, except without the lethal amounts of pride.

Comment: But they were taken in life not in death... I think you only go to the wherever  it was if you are a master of chi.

Comment: @Rincewind: I'm not sure I follow. Kai took the Chi of plenty of Kung Fu masters while he was in the spirit world, including Oogway's. If you consider the spirit world the place where spirits of the dead reside (citation needed - I'd argue that's not true), then there shouldn't be any way for for Kai to get out, or Po for that matter.

Answer (score 5):

### He died (probably).

According the the script for [Kung Fu Panda](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Kung-Fu-Panda.html), Tai Lung got himself ***Ka-Thoomed***.

Since it happened [off-screen](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KilledOffScreen), I think we can be *reasonably* sure that he  died, rather than experiencing any mystical conversion to a spiritual plane of existence.

> **TAI LUNG:** *You're bluffing. You're bluffing! Shifu didn't teach you that.*
>
> **PO:** *Nope. I figured it out.*
>
> He flexes his pinky...
>
> **PO** (CONT'D): *Skadoosh!*
>
> **KA-THOOM!**
>
> [EXT. VALLEY OF PEACE]
>
> A mushroom cloud appears over the Valley, sweeping past the Furious
> Five and the fleeing villagers.

Notably, in the follow-up special "[Kung Fu Panda Holiday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vKpY9TmUWE)", when Tai-Lung appears in a dream, **Po states that he was sure that Tai Lung was dea[d].**

[image: A giant Tai Lung looms over Mr. Ping and Po, who says "Tai Lung? I thought you were dea..." as Tai Lung smashes them with his paw.]

And in the [Legends of Awesomeness](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/Master_and_the_Panda) series, Po is pretty explicit about having killed Tai Lung.

> **Po:** *Hmm… Tai Lung, did you say? Hm, yes. Sounds familiar.
> But I—*
>
> **Peng:** ***They say you destroyed him.** But that… that can’t be true. You’re
> my hero, Po. Please. Please tell me it’s not true.*
>
> **Po:** ***Yes, I did it!** I skadooshed your uncle!*
>
> <sub><sup>[Master and the Panda](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/Master_and_the_Panda/Transcript)</sup></sub>

Comment: So, why didn't Po **Ka-Thoom** himself, then, when he used the technique on his own finger? He clearly didn't die.

Comment: @Ellesedil - You clearly don't understand the first thing about Ka-Thooming and I can't spare the time teach you. You must seek a new master.

Comment: @Ellesedil - Po shows great resilience to supposedly deadly attacks. His blubber absorbs them all. That's presumably how he survived his own Ka-Thoom.

Comment: Eh... I'm not sure that passes the smell test for a mystical attack that doesn't appear to inflict any physical blows. Also, I was left with the impression from Po's dialog that he simply expected transportation for himself and Kai, not death. I'm open to being convinced otherwise, though. And the clip from the special is also a pretty solid reference towards Tai Lung being dead and not in the spirit world.

Comment: Dude I think "Dead" and "spirit world" are the same thing!

Comment: @BinaryWorrier The problem is that third movie seems to go out of its way to avoid mentioning people are dead and instead refer to the spirit world directly. So, the impression I got was that the two are distinctly different. Oogway's scrolls about Kai even mentions that he banished Kai, not killed him. Then there's the fact that two people leave the spirit world to return to the material world in the movie, which would theoretically be pretty difficult if you those people were dead.

Comment: Apologies, what I - rather flippantly - tried to say is, stop thinking of "death" and "the spirit world" as two different things. "Ah but what about the physical mass of their bodies? Does it go to the spirit world? Does it come back?" I say you can't think about it that way, those concepts aren't known where the story is set, it's magical realism at it's best. If you start questioning that you've to question how a praying mantis can hold thousands of pounds of weight (rope bridge scene in first movie). If you do that you will start questioning talking animals and then no one here looks good!

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: I actually don't have any of those questions; the answers are mostly obvious. If "dead" and "spirit world" are the same thing, then Tai Lung is in the spirit world. If he is, Kai probably should have looked him up and taken his Chi considering how strong he was. But even if there's a reasonable reason for overlooking it, the third movie *completely avoids talking about killing any of the characters*. The dialog always specifically talks about sending someone (back) to the spirit world and that travel between the two is possible. This strongly implies they're separate states.

Comment: At this point, I'm starting to believe it's just a plot hole while considering all 3 movies together.

Comment: I say you he ded!
@BinaryWorrier No, the two are separate -- this is shown in the 3rd movie.

Comment: Having watched the movie again recently with my sons, I have to agree that there is a difference between "death" and "the spirit realm". I stand corrected.

Comment: It's worth noting in the TV show 'kung fu panda legends of awesomeness' tai lung is defiantly dead. Tai's  nephew hated po for it. Though I suppose that has dubious canonicity

Comment: how can one be defiantly dead? death is the ultimate end of all defiance.

Answer (score 5):

If you freeze the screen at the right moment you can actually see Tai Lung at Kai´s belt. You can see it once he defeats Monkey and Viper.

[image: Tai Lung at Kai’s Belt]

Comment: Do you have the time stamp for this you can [edit] in?

Answer (score 0):

Kai defeated Tai Lung as you can see on Kai's belt when he takes Monkey's chi. You see Tai Lung as a green gem on the belt so that means he was in the spirit world. That also means he still is in there after the defeat of Kai.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to suggest this means he was in the spirit world? Any quotations you can provide?

Comment: This is the best picture I can get of Kai's belt in the scene you mention: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVtFf.png  So... which one of these things is Tai Lung?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Tai Lung survived in *Kung Fu Panda*, and is *not* in the spirit world.

The next time you see him, he had his chi taken by Kai, which would lead one to infer that Kai later fought Tai Lung, with Kai winning and taking Tai Lung's chi.

Comment: Do you have any evidence supporting this?

Comment: look on villains wiki and kung fu panda wiki and it will say he survived and got his chi taken by kai

Answer (score -1):

Well, honestly I think Tai is still alive somehow. I just saw KFP3 again and I noticed that Po pulls his finger completely when doing the Wuxi finger hold and in the first movie he just flexed it. I know it's something very subtle but that could mean why all the ying yang stuff didn't happened but just think about it. What if he didn't kill him intentionally, that will explain the difference between the finger hold in the movies, and the fact that there were no petals on the place where he vanished Tai.

Answer (score -2):

If you look closely at Kai's belt, you will see Tai Lung as a gem. The only way this could be possible is if Kai encouneed Tai in the Spirit Realm and they more than likely fought, resulting in Kai turning Tai into a gem. This lead me to believe that he isn't simply dead, but he was banished to the Spirit Realm. This could also mean that Tai could find a way to break out of the Spirit Realm just as Tai did, and possibly a return.

Comment: Are you sure he's on Kai's belt? Like I commented on a similar answer to yours, this is the best image I could find of his belt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVtFf.png  So, which one is Tai Lung? If he's not in the shot, then provide additional evidence because I've watched this movie several times looking myself and don't see him.